How to scroll to today in a custom calendar control?
I am implementing a horizontal CalendarView in my Maui application.
My plan when the app starts the calendar is scrolled to today, automatically. However this does not work as expected, but when I navigate to another tab and back it works.
I call the ScrollTo method in the OnAppearing method.
My custom CalendarView
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <StackLayout
        x:Class="App.Controls.CalendarView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:App.Controls"
        xmlns:models="clr-namespace:App.Models"
        x:Name="this">
    
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label
                FontSize="Subtitle"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=Today, StringFormat='{0:MMMM}'}"
                TextColor="{DynamicResource TextColor}"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Button
                Padding="10"
                BorderWidth="0"
                Clicked="JumpToToday_Button_Clicked"
                CornerRadius="10"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                HeightRequest="40"
                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                Style="{DynamicResource PrimaryActionOutlineButtonStyle}"
                Text="Jump to today"
                TextTransform="Uppercase"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </StackLayout>
        <CollectionView
            x:Name="DateCollectionView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=Dates}"
            ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="10" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:CalendarModel">
                    <controls:CardView
                        Padding="10"
                        RowDefinitions="30,30"
                        RowSpacing="0"
                        WidthRequest="60">
                       <Label
                            FontSize="Caption"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:ddd}'}"
                            TextColor="{DynamicResource TextColor}"
                            VerticalOptions="End">
                            <Label.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger
                                    Binding="{Binding IsCurrentDate}"
                                    TargetType="Label"
                                    Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource OnSurfaceColor}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Label.Triggers>
                        </Label>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Subtitle"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd}'}"
                            TextColor="{DynamicResource TextColor}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger
                                    Binding="{Binding IsCurrentDate}"
                                    TargetType="Label"
                                    Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource OnSurfaceColor}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Label.Triggers>
                        </Label>
                        <controls:CardView.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger
                                Binding="{Binding IsCurrentDate}"
                                TargetType="controls:CardView"
                                Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger
                                Binding="{Binding IsCurrentDate}"
                                TargetType="controls:CardView"
                                Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundSecondaryColor}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </controls:CardView.Triggers>
                        <controls:CardView.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=CurrentDateCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                        </controls:CardView.GestureRecognizers>
                    </controls:CardView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>

CodeBehind:
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace App.Controls;
    
    public partial class CalendarView : StackLayout
    {
    #region BindableProperty
        public static readonly BindableProperty CompletedDatesProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(CompletedDates),
            typeof(List<DateTime>),
            declaringType: typeof(CalendarView),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            defaultValue: new List<DateTime>());
    
        public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedDateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(SelectedDate),
            typeof(DateTime),
            declaringType: typeof(CalendarView),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            defaultValue: DateTime.Now,
            propertyChanged: SelectedDatePropertyChanged);
    
        public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedDateCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(SelectedDateCommand),
            typeof(ICommand),
            declaringType: typeof(CalendarView));
        #endregion
    
        private static void SelectedDatePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue) 
        {
            var controls  = (CalendarView)bindable;
            if (newValue != null)
            {
                var newDate = (DateTime)newValue;
                if (controls._tempDate.Month == newDate.Month && controls._tempDate.Year == newDate.Year)
                {
                    var currentDate = controls.Dates.Where(_ => _.Date == newDate.Date).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (currentDate != null)
                    {
                        controls.Dates.ToList().ForEach(_ => _.IsCurrentDate = false);
                        currentDate.IsCurrentDate = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    controls.BindDates(newDate);
    
                }
            }
        }
    
        public List<DateTime> CompletedDates
        {
            get => (List<DateTime>)GetValue(CompletedDatesProperty);
            set => SetValue(CompletedDatesProperty, value);
        }
    
        public DateTime SelectedDate
        {
            get => (DateTime)GetValue(SelectedDateProperty);
            set => SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value);
        }
    
        public DateTime Today => DateTime.Today;
    
        public ICommand SelectedDateCommand
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(SelectedDateCommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(SelectedDateCommandProperty, value);
        }
    
        public event EventHandler<DateTime> OnDateSelected;
    
    
        private DateTime _tempDate;
    
        public ObservableCollection<CalendarModel> Dates { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CalendarModel>();
    
        public CalendarView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindDates(DateTime.Now);
        }
    
        private void BindDates(DateTime selectedDate)
        {
            Dates.Clear();
            int daysCount = DateTime.DaysInMonth(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month);
    
            for (int day = 1; day <= daysCount; day++)
            {
                Dates.Add(new CalendarModel
                {
                    Date = new DateTime(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month, day),
                    IsCompletedDate = CompletedDates.Any(_ => _.Date.Year == selectedDate.Year && _.Date.Month == selectedDate.Month && _.Date.Day == day)
                });
            }
    
            Dates.FirstOrDefault(_=>_.Date.Date == selectedDate.Date).IsCurrentDate = true;
        }
    
        #region Command
        public ICommand CurrentDateCommand => new Command<CalendarModel>((currentDate) =>
        {
            _tempDate = currentDate.Date;
            SelectedDate = currentDate.Date;
            OnDateSelected?.Invoke(null, currentDate.Date);
            SelectedDateCommand?.Execute(currentDate.Date);
        });
    
        public void ScrollToToday()
        {
            var today = Dates.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Date.Date == Today.Date);
    
            DateCollectionView.ScrollTo(today, ScrollToPosition.Center);
        }
        #endregion
    
        private void JumpToToday_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) => ScrollToToday();
    }

In my DashboardMainPage:
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();
   await vm.InitializeAsync();
   calendarView.ScrollToToday();
}

Problem:
When the app starts and first time OnAppearing is called the CalendarView is scrolled to the end of the list, when I navigate to another Tab and back to DashboardMainPage the CalendarView is scrolled to today as expected.
What can go wrong here? Any good calendarview package to use in maui?
When app starts


When navigate on shell tab and back


DashboardMainPage:
 <controls:CalendarView
     x:Name="calendarView"
     Margin="10"
     CompletedDates="{Binding CompletedDates}" />

code behind
public DashboardMainPage(DashboardMainViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = vm;
}

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    await vm.InitializeAsync();
   
    calendarView.ScrollToToday();
   
}

In my DashboardMainViewModel
public ObservableCollection<DateTime> CompletedDates { get; } = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>();

internal async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    if (IsInitialized)
    {
        return;
    }

    await LoadDataAsync();
}

private async Task LoadDataAsync()
{
    try
    {
        // Set busy indicators
        SetDataLoadingIndicators(true);
        LoadingText = "Loading...";

        // Clear collections
        CompletedDates.Clear();
                    var allForCurrentMonthTask = _unitOfWork.Data.GetAllForCurrentMonthAsync();

   CompletedDates.AddRange(allForCurrentMonthTask.Result.Select(item =>
            new DateTime(item.StartTime.Year, item.StartTime.Month, item.StartTime.Day)));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
    finally
    {
        SetDataLoadingIndicators(false);
    }

    IsInitialized = true;
}



Could you please show the full code so that I can create a sample to test? In addition, if  the calendarView.ScrollToToday(); execute when the vm.InitializeAsync() is not completed will cause this problem?

I updated the code with DashboardMainPage, on first load ScrollToToday is called from OnAppearing of the DashboardMainPage but unfortunatelly it always scrolls to the end of the list not to the desired item. Even during debug it selects the correct element. When I navigate to another page on the Shell Tab and back it works well.

I added a gif to show whats going on. By default it scrolls to the end instead of the current date when I use tab navigation and back it scrolls to the correct date.

There are still some classes missed such as cardview and _unitOfWork. So I can't create a sample. But according to the gif : because the OnAppearing method will be called every time when the page shows, the first time when the ScrollToToday() called, it didn't scroll to the correct position, but the second time it called, it can. The only cause I can think about is the vm.InitializeAsync();. It's async. It's not completed when the  ScrollToToday() methoed run first time.

You are totally right, I have added await Task.Delay(500); right after await vm.InitializeAsync(); and now for the first open it scrolls to the correct date. Any other way instead of adding Task.Delay?

The Task.Delay is a good and easy solution. You can try the other ways in my answer.

So you can try to put the calendarView.ScrollToToday(); into the method that executes after the OnAppearing() method. Such as OnSizeAllocated method:
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
     base.OnAppearing();
     await vm.InitializeAsync();
}

protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
    calendarView.ScrollToToday();
}

Of course, there are some other methods such as OnHandlerChanged() and so on.
In addition, you can try to refer to this case: Calling async method synchronously.
